# Can not connect to Oracle via VBA - Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr Failed

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, odbc

I have created an ODBC connection for oracle using "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver under user DSN.
I can connect to oracle 10g using SQL developer but when i try to connect via ODBC its saying

> **[Microsoft][ODBC DRIVER Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr Failed**

I have tried following code for connecting.

```
data_src = Oracle
Database = sys
Uid = <my id>
pwd = <my pwd>
Set cn=new ADOBB.Connection
Cn.open "DataSource=" + data_src + ";" + Database + "; persist security Infor = True; UserID= " + Uid + "; Password=" + pwd + "; SessionMode = ANSI;"
```

I have already connected to Teradata using same code with different setting. Please help me to connect Oracle 10g from VBA

Comment: The concatenator for VBA is & not +, + can lead to problems with null values.

Comment: But the same is working fine when i tried connecting Teradata using same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue - see [IBM support post](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21541694). Solution - use the Oracle driver.

Also - connection strings are different between different database drivers.  For example, a connection string for the Microsoft Oracle driver would look like

```
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=myServerAddress;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

while one for Oracle's own driver would be similar to

```
Driver={Oracle in OraHome92};Dbq=myTNSServiceName;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: The link is saying, 
Resolving the problem
When creating a DSN for an‚ ODBC (SQL)‚ map, it can not be created using the Microsoft Driver for Oracle.‚ 

Create the‚ DSN‚ using the Oracle ODBC Driver.

"I want to connect using Mircosoft ODBC" only. Anyhow let me try your code for Microsoft and let you know.