# Can not connect to Oracle via IBM Oracle ODBC Driver

Tags: oracle, vba, odbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can not connect to Oracle via VBA - Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203305/can-not-connect-to-oracle-via-vba-drivers-sqlsetconnectattr-failed)

I am trying to set an ODBC connection for Oracle to connect via VBA.
I created an ODBC entry at USER DSN (using IBM Oracle Driver) but when i Test Connection, it says

> ORA-12154 Error - TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
>   specified

I have given, Server name & user name properly which i used to login Oracle via SQL developer.

I checked tnsnames.ora file, Server entry is there. I have given
hostname as server in USER DSN.

Any idea or suggestion to setup ODBC connection for connecting oracle ?

Comment: @Remou : I tried this with IBM Oracle Driver. The Link was about Microsoft ODBC connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with tnsora.names file. I have solved the TNS problem got resolved.
But I can not retrive data through IBM Oracle ODBC since it is saying to pay to access data via IBM datadirect.
So I am closing this thread.